# How to count previous rows based on a criteria

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm looking for a way to count how many rows appear since the first entry based however I want to exclude the time of day splitting the rows out by AM & PM.

| ID | Time of day | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AM | 05/02/2019 |
| 1 | PM | 05/02/2019 |
| 1 | AM | 06/02/2019 |
| 1 | PM | 06/02/2019 |
| 2 | AM | 04/02/2019 |
| 2 | PM | 04/02/2019 |

The end result I'm looking for should produce a running count of the rows based on the ID and date whilst excluding the AM/PM logic shown below in the `count` column.

| ID | Time of day | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AM | 05/02/2019 | 1 |
| 1 | PM | 05/02/2019 | 1 |
| 1 | AM | 06/02/2019 | 2 |
| 1 | PM | 06/02/2019 | 2 |
| 2 | AM | 04/02/2019 | 1 |
| 2 | PM | 04/02/2019 | 1 |
| 2 | AM | 05/02/2019 | 2 |
| 2 | PM | 05/02/2019 | 2 |
| 2 | AM | 06/02/2019 | 3 |
| 2 | PM | 06/02/2019 | 3 |

I'm currently using:

```
row_number () over(partition by ID order by date)
```

However this does not take into account the AM/PM logic that I want to exclude.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only exactly **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to add the time_of_day column to the partition, so the AM/PM rows are enumerated in separate rows:

```
row_number() over(partition by id, time_of_day order by date)
```